# How to unsubscribe from redux store when component will unmount? How to decorate redux connect?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux, react-redux

I am passing the following props (storeName) to my component:

```
<MyComponent reducerName="city" />
```

and I want to connect to store with a dynamic name (this.props.reducerName)

for example

```
export default connect(state => ({
    some: state[this.props.reducerName]
}), { })(MyComponent);
```

How to decorate redux connect, or what i must to do?

I tried to skip redux connect and used store.subscribe

```
componentDidMount() {
    store.subscribe(() => {
        this.setState({some: store.getState([this.props.reducerName]});
    });
}
```

But when I move to another page, I see the following error:

> Warning: setState(...): Can only update a mounted or mounting
>   component. This usually means you called setState() on an unmounted
>   component. This is a no-op.

How to unsubscribe from redux store when component will unmount?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`connect` has a second parameter of `ownProps`, which is an object containing all passed-in props. You would do something like this:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state, { reducerName = 'defaultReducer' }) => ({
  some: state[reducerName],
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(MyComponent);
```

Answer (score 62):

To unsubscribe you can simple execute the function return by `store.subscribe`:

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.unsubscribe = store.subscribe(() => {
    // ...
  });
}
componentWillUnmount() {
  this.unsubscribe();
}
```

Comment: It's this kind of nonsense that makes people (including myself sometimes) claim that JavaScript is wack.

Comment: I don't understand, what nonsense do you refer to?

Comment: My apologies. The nonsense I was referring to is the kind of practice where one has to set a variable with a name like 'unsubscribe' whose value is the function that you wish to unsubscribe from but which is run when the variable is declared. I take issue with Redux's practice of handling the unsubscription within the subscribe method and not with your explanation of how this is done which is right on the money.

Comment: Oh, now I'm curious. Is there a better pattern for handling subscribe/unsubscribe in this context?

Comment: I don't know whether there is a better way of handling sub/unsub _in this context_, but this is largely because the creators of Redux have constructed the `subscribe` method and thereby control the context in which sub/unsub actions can occur. Perhaps this makes more sense to better minds than my own, but I feel that the syntax is confusing on the face of it because it gives a variable/property a name that seemingly contradicts its value (ie, unsubscribe = subscribe). While it may be more verbose, I prefer subscribe and unsubscribe be separate methods, as they are for event subscriptions.

Comment: @flyingace I think you are misunderstanding the code, or then I am misunderstanding you. `store.subscribe()` returns a new function, which unsubscribes. I guess `store.subscribe()` could have returned an id, or a subscription object that has an `unsubscribe` method, but the way it is is much more direct.

Comment: This is amazing, but could someone explain, why this works?

Comment: Because it is designed to work like that, you can check the documentation for `subscribe` method here https://redux.js.org/api/store#subscribe

Comment: this is a great way to handle holding the reference to the unsubscribe function and cleaning it up later - you dont have to name it `unsubscribe` @flyingace and this is typically how the world does things for unsubscribing

Comment: If I didn't `unsubscribe` in `componentWillUnmount()`, will this cause memory leaks?